# Getting [errno 111] using mosquitto sending to web interface

Tags: python, html, websocket, mosquitto

I have setup a mosquitto client that sends data to a dygraph script which plots the data real time. My issue is that sometimes, when i close the dygraph html window, the terminal from which my mqtt script sends the data comes with the line "errno 104 connection reset by peer". After this, if I close and reopen my mqtt script, it won't run with the message "socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused"

I have enabled websockets in order to send data to my html file, so there must be a conflict there.

The mqtt code is:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time
import random

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):                #function to call on connect
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe("topic1/")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):                      #function to call on message
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.reinitialise()                                       #initiate mqtt client
#client.on_connect = on_connect
#client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("localhost", 1883, 60)                       #connect to broker
client.loop_start()

while True:

    client.publish("topic1/", random.uniform(-20, 20))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

and the websocket from which my html file reads the data is:

```
var MQTTport = 9001;
```

9001 is what I have said to be the websocket in the mqtt config file.

So why does it crash when i press I close the tab in the html window but runs normally if I keep it open?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Haven't any definition (Exception handle) on broken pipe, add a handle function for `close` method. Or you got missing parameters on init.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further about the first sentence please? Thank you.